# fancy box problems with dynamic gallery being opened from single hyper link for each gallery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, fancybox

I've setup a fancybox gallery on my page. I have a requirement such that there are thumbnails of image of particular category, but when someone taps that thumbnail they should be show with   images in that category in fancy box.
So for that what I'm doing is on page load i've populated javascript array for various categories with values of their sub images in their associated variable.

My code is :

```
<script>
var cat1=['a.jpg'];
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(".manual2").click(function() {
        var cat_gallery_id = this.id;
        $.fancybox(cat_gallery_id, {
            'padding'           : 0,
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'type'              : 'image',
            'changeFade'        : 1
        });
       });
    });
</script>
```

Inside my body element I have various links as :

```
<a href="#" class="manual2" id="cat1">Click</a>
```

Now this  tags are set in such a way that each one of them will have same class only their id's will vary. When any one of the is clicked I am fetching the id by `this.id`

But when I do so it gives me error like this in error console :

```
GET http://localhost/myproject/cat1 404 (Not Found)
```

but instead of using cat_gallery_id as the first attribute passed to fancybox function if I pass the same variable statically like

```
$.fancybox(cat1, {
```

the fancybox works perfectly fine. I am sure I am doing something wrong with basic assignment of value after getting from `this.id`

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cat1` is a variable array where as `this.id` represents a string of 'cat1', not the array variable - what you may want to do is use an associative array to store your arrays:

```
var cats = {};
cats['cat1'] = ['a.jpg'];

$(".manual2").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.fancybox(cats[this.id], {
        'padding'           : 0,
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',
        'type'              : 'image',
        'changeFade'        : 1
    });
});
```

Or you could just convert the string into the variable using `window[this.id]`.  Eg

```
$.fancybox(window[this.id], ...etc
```